# Is there an R function to extract only numbers from a comma-separated string with many NA values to create a column with only the numbers?

Tags: r, string, na, numeric

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
 before = data.frame(diag1 = c(1,NA, 1, NA, NA, 1), diag2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA), diag3 = c(3, NA, NA, NA, 3, 3), diag4 = c(4, 4, NA, NA, 4, NA))

  diag1 diag2 diag3 diag4
1     1    NA     3     4
2    NA    NA    NA     4
3     1    NA    NA    NA
4    NA     2    NA    NA
5    NA    NA     3     4
6     1    NA     3    NA
```

I have been trying to find a solution in which the end result is a new column named "diagnoses" that looks like this

```
  diagnoses
1     1,3,4
2         4
3         1
4         2
5       3,4
6       1,3
```

This is just a much smaller example of my real problem. In the dataset I am working on there are over 70 columns of diagnoses, with no more than 3 numeric values in each row. I have tried strsplit, separate, unite functions. I still haven't found an elegant solution

I have used apply paste function

```
dat$diagnoses<- apply( (dat[ , cols]), 1, function(x) paste(na.omit(x),collapse=", ") )
```

However, it yields a string with many commas.

I tried gsub to substitute the , but I still have not been able to get the results I hoped.

This is the output I have been able to get: `"1,,3,4,," ",,,4,," " 1,,,,," ",2,,,," ",,3,4,," "1,,3,,,"`

Comment: Not able to reproduce your issue with the code as it is working fine for me.  May be you have `""` instead of `NA`s

Comment: Thank you! You are right, I had not converted all of the variables into numeric before doing this in my big dataset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option is to loop through the row with `apply`, remove the `NA` elements and `paste` it together

```
before$new <- apply(before, 1, function(x) toString(x[!is.na(x)]))
before$new
#[1] "1, 3, 4" "4"       "1"       "2"       "3, 4"    "1, 3"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility could be:

```
before$rowid <- 1:nrow(before)
aggregate(values ~ rowid, 
          paste0, collapse = ",",
          data.frame(before[5], stack(before[-5])))

  rowid values
1     1  1,3,4
2     2      4
3     3      1
4     4      2
5     5    3,4
6     6    1,3
```

Comment: @akrun now I see. Anyway, I don't think it is a good idea to use `apply()` in the case of data.frames, so I will leave it here as an alternative.

Comment: For rowwise, `apply` is the best  (assuming that the columns are all numeric).  Doing this in `aggregate` with a created grouping sequence may not add any efficiency

Comment: could you please clarify what this part does exactly?(before[5[, stack(before[-5])))

Comment: Sure :) `data.frame(before[5], stack(before[-5]))` is used to create the df on which the aggregation is performed. `stack(before[-5])` essentially transforms the data from wide to long format, excluding column 5 which is a newly created rowid. `before[5]` containing the rowid is then recycled according the length of `stack(before[-5])`

Answer (score 2):

```
foo = function(..., sep = ","){
    paste(..., sep = sep)
}

gsub(",?NA|NA,?", "", do.call(foo, before))
#[1] "1,3,4" "4"     "1"     "2"     "3,4"   "1,3"
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know `toString` but borrowing from @akrun and using package *purrr* :

```
purrr::pmap_chr(before, ~toString(na.omit(c(...))))
# [1] "1, 3, 4" "4"       "1"       "2"       "3, 4"    "1, 3"
```